# how to get password using Yii::app()->User

Tags: php, yii

I want to know why when I use `var_dump(Yii::app()->User->id);`

I get the **id** number,

and when i use `var_dump(Yii::app()->User->password);`

I get the following error:

**CException
CAssetManager.basePath "/opt/local/www/projects/theuniversalgroup/app/webim/operator/assets" is invalid. Please make sure the directory exists and is writable by the Web server process.**

Also how can I get the **password** of the *user* so i can use it to log in into the web app.

Comment: You should never store password as plain-text or any other format that can be converted back to original password.

Comment: ok, Thanks Leri, i will have that on my mind.

Comment: Try to chmod (edit permissions) the /assets/  directory to 755 or 777 (if 755 doesn't work)

Comment: already try that, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get user password using interface

```
var_dump(Yii::app()->user->password);
```

use this method, then you need add in your base component file `UserIdentity.php`

```
common/components/base/UserIdentity.php 


   public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function getName() {
        return $this->username;
    }




   public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }
```

after this change you will be able to use password using the method:

```
var_dump(Yii::app()->user->password);
```

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding is correct you are trying to create a login for your app in that case you can use something like this to log into you app , this is how i set up my userIdentity.php ;

```
    class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
        private $_id;


    public function authenticate()
    {
            $username = strtolower($this->username);
            $user = User::model()->find('LOWER(user_name)=?',array($username));
            if($user===null)
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
            else if(!$user->validatePassword($this->password))
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
            else{
                $this->_id = $user->id_user;
                $this->username=$user->user_name;
                $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
                $user->updateLoginDate();
            }
            return $this->errorCode==self::ERROR_NONE;
    }

        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->_id;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When submit the login form, model LoginForm.php [protected/models/LoginForm.php] instantiate the UseIdentity.php [protected/components/SiteController.php] class to check user and password. If login info is correct, UseIdentity class saves the user id.

Please check the following files:

- login.php [protected/views/login.php]
- LoginForm.php [protected/models/LoginForm.php]
- SiteController.php [protected/controllers/SiteController.php]
- UseIdentity.php [protected/components/SiteController.php]

So you find the logged in user id when you try as `var_dump(Yii::app()->User->id);`. I answered earlier in you another post that how to get the password. If you would like to save the password as user id you should use `$this->setState();` method in UserIdentity class. there are many ways to get or hold the password.